# GooleMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_HYBRID) not working

Tags: android, google-maps

Method here:

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);       
        LatLng position = new LatLng(x, y);        
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15));
        geoJsonLayer.addLayerToMap();
    }
```

When I choose: MAP_TYPE_HYBRID, MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE or MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN - map is opened, shape is shown (with JSON), but no background - just small squares, no image.

MAP_TYPE_NORMAL - is working good - getting map image, roads etc. + shape on it.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Problem solved by reinstalling application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling application